# socket.io get data from onclick action then pass the data to other pages to execute the data

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to create a page using node.js and socket.io.

There are two buttons inside the page, when I click one of them, it will change a variable which defines the animation-duration(I omit the CSS animation codes here).

When I open the same page on another web-browser and click one of the buttons, I hope to see the change in both of the webpages. I don't know how to write the code inside the `socket.on('chat', function(data){???});` to make two pages communicate with each other.

Client side:

//socket.io codes--

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('chat', function  (data)
    {
         function change_position(data)
          {
           document.getElementById("animation1").style.WebkitAnimationDuration=data;
          }
    });

 </script>

.....
```

//action--

```
<body>
<button id="1b" type="button" style="position:absolute; left:377px; top:220px;" value="2s"; onclick="change_position(value)"> - 1 - </button>

<button id="2b" type="button" style="position:absolute; left:477px; top:220px;" value="15s"; onclick="change_position(value)"> - 2 - </button>
</body>
```

server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
  connect = require('connect');

var app = connect().use(connect.static('public')).listen(3000);
var chat_room = io.listen(app);

chat_room.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('chat', function  (data) {
    chat_room.sockets.emit('chat', data);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If your want a message to propagate to all clients/sockets, in your server you should have something like:

```
chat_room.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

  socket.on('chat', function  (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('chat', data);
    socket.emit('chat',data);
  });

});
```

The line `socket.emit('chat',data);` allows you to send the message back also to the sender of it, because broadcast will send it all *other* sockets.

Of course, you could ommit that line and handle the message sending logic in the client; i.e. adding some JavaScript code that makes the changes you want just after sending the message to the server.

Comment: can you tell where I was doing wrong? I meaning the logical conflict of my code in terms of socket.io part

Comment: The line `chat_room.sockets.emit('chat', data);` doesn't seem to me to be good, since you don't want to emit a message from the server to every socket (that's what that line says, but I'm not really sure if that even works).

With the code I suggested, `socket.broadcast.emit('chat', data);`you are saying: "The socket named `socket` will broadcast a message triggering the `chat` action in all other sockets, sending `data` as parameter"

Answer (score 0):

You can emit on your client using socket.emit('message', data). Then on the server get it with chat_room.socket.on('message', data). Emit it to the clients using chat_room.sockets.emit('message', data).